# It has this error: [Err] 1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update something in my table

**update member, dept set member.collectoridno = "759" where member.contractno = dept.contractno and member.collectoridno = "722" and dept.aging = "30" LIMIT 66;**